# In Scala, how do I build a factory for nested types, outside of the containing class?

Tags: scala

Explained with an example:

```
class A {
    def f = {
        val b: B = C.factory(this).asInstanceOf[B]
    }
    class B
}

object C {
    def factory(a: A): A#B = new a.B
}
```

`C.factory` is a function for creating a new instance of an `A#B`. Since `B` is a nested type, I've included an `A` reference in the function signature. The calling function `f` has to cast the reference returned from `factory`, which I'd like to avoid. Without the cast I get:

```
error: type mismatch;
found   : A#B
required: A.this.B
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on what you want. In `A`, B means `this.B`, that is a `B` that is created from the enclosing instance. Indeed your factory returns that, but it does not say so. It just says it returns the `A#B` (called a *type projection*), a `B` of some unspecified `A` instance. If, for your val b, you don't care by which A instance it was created, then you should say so with val b: A#B (or let the compiler infer it).

If you do care that it is a B from your A and no other, you might be out of luck. Your `factory` returns an instance of `B` created by the `a` parameter. But your signature does not says so. You would want `a.B` rather than the less precise type projection `A#B`. Alas, the language does not allow that. You will get an error *illegal dependent method type*: when you write a dependent type `a.B`, `a` must be a "stable identifier" and a method parameter is not considered one. Maybe [this blog post](http://scalide.blogspot.com/2010/06/working-around-dependent-method-types.html) may help

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I would like my factory function to return a.B, but as you say, that does not compile.

Comment: You can enable dependent method types without the rest of the experimental features using the option `-Ydependent-method-types`. This feature is not officially supported, but maybe that will change.